# Can I push my own User object into Spring's SecurityContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security and have followed some basic recipes to get Spring Security working in my application, but now I'm trying to see if there is a way to get my own User object added to Spring's SecurityContext upon login/authentication.

My security is currently configured to use the JdbcDaoImpl:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="com.ia.security.SpringSecurityDao" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="com.ia.security.SpringSecurityDao" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value>select username,password,enabled 
        from user 
        where username = ?
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value>SELECT R.ID, R.NAME, P.NAME
            FROM ROLE R
            JOIN USER_ROLE UR on R.id = UR.role_id
            JOIN USER U on U.id = UR.user_id
            JOIN ROLE_PERMISSION RP ON RP.role_id = R.id
            JOIN PERMISSION P ON P.id = RP.permission_id
            WHERE U.username=?
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I realize that I can retrieve the `Principal` object from the SecurityContext and get the username and requery the DB given the username, but was thinking it would be easier to simple store the my entire `User` object in the SecurityContext to have it easily accessible whenever I need it throughout my application as opposed to just storing the username, password and enabled fields in the `UserDetails` object.

I've looked into the UserDetailsService, and more specifically the `JdbcDaoImpl` class, but not entirely sure of the best way to proceed.  If I simply override/extend by calling `super.loadUserByUsername` the `loadUserByUsername` method to return my own UserDetails object is that sufficient?  Then would I just be able to do `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()` and cast it to my own object?

I've found other posts on StackOverflow that relate to this, but most seem to be ignoring anything to do with Authorities and Roles that are retrieved from the DB, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer:
Yes you can do exactly as you planned. Keep in mind that some functionality like "hasRole" checks the authorities list and not the user details by default.

The long answer:
Keeping a user object in the securitycontext, which is held in the session can have some side effects.
This is particularly true when you are using hibernate. Lazy exceptions anyone? ;)
We went this route first and several calls later some LIEs happend which was quite tricky to follow up. Using the OpenSessionInView filter, we thought we are safe, but that's just wrong as in the next request the session is gone. So we loaded more related objects from the user and it still happend. Just later :)

We had three options. Either merge the user object on each request, create a pojo holding just the neccessary security information in the userdetails, or just keep the principal (login) in the security context and load the user object once it's needed.

We went with the third solution as hibernate does a good job using the second level cache.
As a side effect the security is now more reliable as spring security gets now the latest version of a user on each request and does not work with "stale" user roles.

So if you dont use hibernate or you can guarantee that no LIEs will happen go for solution one or two. Else i would recommend our approach.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Although I must admit I'm not familiar with the acronym LIE; I presume it is something related to Lazy Initialization Exception (or something of the sorts).  Indeed, I am using Hibernate, and wanted to retain the User object in the SecurityContext for reference purposes.  More specifically, I have audit fields that require the current-logged-in user, and figured it would be easier to just use the SecurityContext's User object to retrieve that than have to retrieve it from the DB every time.  Can you give me more details/experiences on the LIEs that you encountered?

Comment: I just reread your answer, and am confused by "...more reliable as spring security gets now the latest version of a user on each request...".  How is that?  SpringSecurity will query the DB upon your login and store that info in the SecurityContext, including any authorities.  How does it make any difference whether or not you are keeping the entire User entity around in the UserDetails for the stale-ness of the data in the SecurityContext?

Comment: As we keep only the login in the security context we have to load the user entity on each request. As this fetches the "latest" version of a user and this is now an attached entity we are not running into lazy exceptions. Now about the autorities; thinking back, I'm not sure anymore if we changed the behaviour of the authorities check to look it up from the user entity assigned roles or if we did something else to use the correct version here too. Happy to discuss that, but not here in the comments :)

Comment: After reading your comments and suggestions, I ended up following your recommendations.  Instead of pushing the entire User object into the SecurityContext, I have simply stored the userId as well to facilitate caching and speeding up lookups from the L2 cache.  Thanks!